# Form is not getting submitted - using Formik, yup and reactjs

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, formik, yup, react-state

I'm actually new to reactjs and trying to submit a registration form using Formik, yup, mui. There are 5 fields - username(text field), roles(select-dropdown), collage(select-dropdown), password(text field, type-password) and confirm password(text field, type-password) and a submit button.

I have 2 issues:

1. The form is not getting submitted. I tried to submit by logging just 'username' to console. Nothing can be seen in console. I have currently commented the other sections, only username section is live.
2. The Mui's Select element is not working when added to the form. The select I'm using is the react native select(correct me if I'm wrong). I'm not sure of how to pass select's response to submit the form.

I initially thought that select was giving problem when submitting but when I removed it, it still doesn't submit. Select may give additional errors too.

Please help me out and let me know where I'm making mistakes. Thanks in advance.

This is the component-form:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { Link as RouterLink } from 'react-router-dom';
import Select from '@mui/material/Select';
import { Menu } from '@mui/material';

// material-ui
import {
    Box,
    Button,
    FormControl,
    FormHelperText,
    Grid,
    Link,
    IconButton,
    InputAdornment,
    InputLabel,
    OutlinedInput,
    Stack,
    Typography
} from '@mui/material';

// third party
import * as Yup from 'yup';
import { Formik } from 'formik';

// project import
import AnimateButton from 'components/@extended/AnimateButton';
import { strengthColor, strengthIndicator } from 'utils/password-strength';

// assets
import { EyeOutlined, EyeInvisibleOutlined } from '@ant-design/icons';

// ============================|| FIREBASE - REGISTER ||============================ //

const AuthRegister = () => {
    const [level, setLevel] = useState();
    const [showPassword, setShowPassword] = useState(false);
    const handleClickShowPassword = () => {
        setShowPassword(!showPassword);
    };

    const handleMouseDownPassword = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
    };
    const [formValues, setformValues] = useState('');
    const [formpassword, setformpassword] = useState('');

    return (
        <>
            <Formik
                initialValues={{
                    username: ''
                    // roles: '',
                    // colleges: '',
                    /* password: '',
                    passwordConfirm: '' */
                }}
                validationSchema={Yup.object().shape({
                    username: Yup.string().email('Must be a valid email').max(255).required('Email is required')
                    /* roles: Yup.string().required('select role first'),
                    colleges: Yup.string().max(255).required('select college first'), 
                    password: Yup.string().max(255).required('Password is required'),
                    passwordConfirm: Yup.string().max(255).required('Confirm Password is required')*/
                })}
                onSubmit={async (values, { setErrors, setStatus, setSubmitting }) => {
                    console.log('entered on submit function');
                    setStatus();
                    console.log('entered on submit function1');
                    setTimeout(() => {
                        console.log(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2));
                        setSubmitting(false);
                        setStatus('success');
                    }, 2000);
                    console.log('entered on submit function3');
                    /*  try {
                        console.log('inside try ');
                        setStatus({ success: false });
                    } catch (err) {
                        console.log('inside catch ');
                        console.error(err);
                        setStatus({ success: false });
                        setErrors({ submit: err.message });
                        setSubmitting(false);
                    } */
                }}
            >
                {({ errors, handleBlur, handleChange, handleSubmit, isSubmitting, touched, values }) => (
                    <form noValidate onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                        <Grid container spacing={3}>
                            <Grid item xs={12}>
                                <Stack spacing={1}>
                                    <InputLabel htmlFor="email-signup">Username*</InputLabel>
                                    <OutlinedInput
                                        id="email-signup"
                                        type="email"
                                        value={formValues.registeremail}
                                        name="registeremail"
                                        onBlur={handleBlur}
                                        onChange={handleChange}
                                        placeholder="abc@gmail.com"
                                        fullWidth
                                        error={Boolean(touched.registeremail && errors.registeremail)}
                                        //inputProps={{}}
                                    />
                                    {touched.registeremail && errors.registeremail && (
                                        <FormHelperText error id="helper-text-email-signup">
                                            {errors.registeremail}
                                        </FormHelperText>
                                    )}
                                </Stack>
                            </Grid>
                            {/* <Grid item xs={12} md={6}>
                                <Stack spacing={1}>
                                    <InputLabel htmlFor="role-signup">Roles*</InputLabel>
                                    <Select
                                        native
                                        onChange={handleChange}
                                        name="roles"
                                        labelid="demo-simple-select-label"
                                        id="role-signup"
                                        value={formValues.roles}
                                        label="roles"
                                    >
                                        <option value="--">--</option>
                                        <option value="Admin">Admin</option>
                                        <option value="Faculty">Faculty</option>
                                        <option value="Student">Student</option>
                                    </Select> */}
                            {/* </Stack>
                            </Grid>
                            <Grid item xs={12}>
                                <Stack spacing={1}>
                                    <InputLabel htmlFor="company-signup">College</InputLabel>
                                    <Select
                                        native
                                        onChange={handleChange}
                                        name="colleges"
                                        labelid="demo-simple-select-label"
                                        id="company-signup"
                                        value={formValues.colleges}
                                        label="colleges"
                                    >
                                        <option value="--">--</option>
                                        <option value="COL1">COL1</option>
                                        <option value="COL2">COL2</option>
                                        <option value="COL3">COL3</option>    
                                        </option>
                                     </Select>
                                    {touched.company && errors.company && (
                                        <FormHelperText error id="helper-text-company-signup">
                                            {errors.company}
                                        </FormHelperText>
                                    )}
                                </Stack>
                            </Grid>
                            <Grid item xs={12}>
                                <Stack spacing={1}>
                                    <InputLabel htmlFor="password_signup">Password</InputLabel>
                                    <OutlinedInput
                                        fullWidth
                                        error={Boolean(touched.password && errors.password)}
                                        id="password_signup"
                                        type={showPassword ? 'text' : 'password'}
                                        name="password"
                                        onBlur={handleBlur}
                                        onChange={handleChange}
                                        value={formValues.password}
                                        endAdornment={
                                            <InputAdornment position="end">
                                                <IconButton
                                                    aria-label="toggle password visibility"
                                                    onClick={handleClickShowPassword}
                                                    onMouseDown={handleMouseDownPassword}
                                                    edge="end"
                                                    size="large"
                                                >
                                                    {showPassword ? <EyeOutlined /> : <EyeInvisibleOutlined />}
                                                </IconButton>
                                            </InputAdornment>
                                        }
                                        placeholder="******"
                                        inputProps={{}}
                                    />
                                    {touched.password && errors.password && (
                                        <FormHelperText error id="helper-text-password-signup">
                                            {errors.password}
                                        </FormHelperText>
                                    )}
                                </Stack>
                                <FormControl fullWidth sx={{ mt: 2 }}>
                                    <Grid container spacing={2} alignItems="center">
                                        <Grid item>
                                            <Box sx={{ bgcolor: level?.color, width: 85, height: 8, borderRadius: '7px' }} />
                                        </Grid>
                                        <Grid item>
                                            <Typography variant="subtitle1" fontSize="0.75rem">
                                                {level?.label}
                                            </Typography>
                                        </Grid>
                                    </Grid>
                                </FormControl>
                            </Grid>
                            <Grid item xs={12}>
                                <Stack spacing={1}>
                                    <InputLabel htmlFor="password-confirm-signup">Confirm Password</InputLabel>
                                    <OutlinedInput
                                        fullWidth
                                        error={Boolean(touched.passwordConfirm && errors.passwordConfirm)}
                                        id="password-confirm-signup"
                                        type={showPassword ? 'text' : 'password'}
                                        name="passwordConfirm"
                                        onBlur={handleBlur}
                                        onChange={handleChange}
                                        value={formValues.passwordConfirm}
                                        endAdornment={
                                            <InputAdornment position="end">
                                                <IconButton
                                                    aria-label="toggle confirm password visibility"
                                                    onClick={handleClickShowPassword}
                                                    onMouseDown={handleMouseDownPassword}
                                                    edge="end"
                                                    size="large"
                                                >
                                                    {showPassword ? <EyeOutlined /> : <EyeInvisibleOutlined />}
                                                </IconButton>
                                            </InputAdornment>
                                        }
                                        placeholder="******"
                                        inputProps={{}}
                                    />
                                    {touched.passwordConfirm && errors.passwordConfirm && (
                                        <FormHelperText error id="helper-text-password-signup">
                                            {errors.passwordConfirm}
                                        </FormHelperText>
                                    )}
                                </Stack>
                                <FormControl fullWidth sx={{ mt: 2 }}>
                                    <Grid container spacing={2} alignItems="center">
                                        <Grid item>
                                            <Box sx={{ bgcolor: level?.color, width: 85, height: 8, borderRadius: '7px' }} />
                                        </Grid>
                                        <Grid item>
                                            <Typography variant="subtitle1" fontSize="0.75rem">
                                                {level?.label}
                                            </Typography>
                                        </Grid>
                                    </Grid>
                                </FormControl>
                            </Grid> */}

                            <Grid item xs={12}>
                                <Typography variant="body2">
                                    By Signing up, you agree to our &nbsp;
                                    <Link variant="subtitle2" component={RouterLink} to="#">
                                        Terms of Service
                                    </Link>
                                    &nbsp; and &nbsp;
                                    <Link variant="subtitle2" component={RouterLink} to="#">
                                        Privacy Policy
                                    </Link>
                                </Typography>
                            </Grid>
                            {errors.submit && (
                                <Grid item xs={12}>
                                    <FormHelperText error>{errors.submit}</FormHelperText>
                                </Grid>
                            )}
                            <Grid item xs={12}>
                                <AnimateButton>
                                    <Button
                                        disableElevation
                                        disabled={isSubmitting}
                                        fullWidth
                                        size="large"
                                        type="submit"
                                        variant="contained"
                                        color="primary"
                                    >
                                        Create Account
                                    </Button>
                                </AnimateButton>
                            </Grid>
                        </Grid>
                    </form>
                )}
            </Formik>
        </>
    );
};

export default AuthRegister;
```

Comment: In validation schema you have used `username` but there is no `username` field. Either change validationSchema or change name of `registeremail` to `username`. Also, Instead of `formValues.registeremail` use `values.registeremail`, `values.roles`....

Comment: Hi Usama, many thanks for your reply. I assigned initial value to username (abc@gmail.com-since it was email field) first and it started submitting but I was getting 2  emails logged, 1. initial value and 2. user entered value.  Your reply pointed out the mistake I made. Thank you for that.  I can console log outputs using both using values and formValues(state variable). Thanks again!